# Raphael element selection problem

Tags: jquery, raphael

Hopefully this is a simple question for any Raphael experts!

I've created a route map where users can click on each country to see the details. It works fine except that passing the mouse over the red line triggers the mouseout event. I need the red line to effectively be just an image on the map and not an interactive element. How do I achieve this?

See the map in action:
http://www.martyn-roberts.co.uk/cycleafrica/route

Thanks!

Comment: +1 For having such an ambitious adventure ahead of you!

Answer (score 0):

You could make an invisible layer over the red line, which triggers the animation on the map.

Answer (score 0):

This answer would have been so elegant a year and a quarter ago...  there's a very simple way of accomplishing this, albeit not directly through Raphael, using the SVG's [pointer-events property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty).  All you need to do is to style the node associated with your route path with pointer-events: none.  In javascript and using jquery, that would be

```
$(routePath.node).css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
```

Or just using javascript directly:

```
routePath.node.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

That will force all mouse events to "drop" onto the elements behind the route.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the [use of pointer events with circles and paths](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/hQUkY/).